# Why is Highstock navigator not showing the candlestick series and showing Volume instead?

Tags: highcharts

When I remove the candlestick series from a Highchart / Highstock chart, then add it back, my chart is showing volume in the navigator, even with showInNavigator is true on the candlestick series. Why?

```
 chartRef.get("candstick_series_id")?.remove(false);
 chartRef.addSeries(series);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because Highstock will automatically add the first series to the navigator, from here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/navigator

> The navigator is enabled by default for the first series in all Highcharts Stock charts.

So if volume is the first series after your remove your candlestick series, volume gets added and your candlestick series gets added as well once you re-add it, but because the candlestick series is much smaller than volume usually, you might not see it. You need to set showInNavigator to false on the other series if you don't want them to be automatically added, for example:

```
series: {
    type: 'line',
    id: "volume_series_id",
    name: "Volume",
    data: stockData.volume,
    yAxis: axisId,
    showInNavigator: false
  }
```